# C# create dynamic class and use it in Threadpool

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to create a dynamic instance of a class at the runtime by using the system.dynamic. and pass it to the threadpool to execute it. But, I am getting an error saying the method in the class is used as a property. Below is the code.

```
Type t = Type.GetType("clsCountrySelectInsertUpdate_TEST");
dynamic dd = Activator.CreateInstance(t, null);
dd.intMode = 203;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(dd.CountrySelectInsertUpdate));
```

I tried to call the method in the threadpool as below as well, but got an error saying that the return type void cannot be converted from the method CountrySelectInsertUpdate.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(dd.CountrySelectInsertUpdate()),null);
```

The method CountrySelectInsertUpdate() does not take a parameter and returns a void.

Any help would be much appericated

Answer (score 0):

[WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx) requires state.  You could easily use a lambda to write this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(state => dd.CountrySelectInsertUpdate()), null);
```

That being said, as you're already using .NET 4, I'd recommend using the TPL instead.  It provides a nicer threading model in general than `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, especially if you later need to get the results (or handle exceptions):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => dd.CountrySelectInsertUpdate());
```